# Overriding balancing pool router supervisor strategy doesn't work

Tags: akka

My worker code:

```
def receive = {
  case msg =>
    throw new Exception("Test exception escalation")
}
```

My controller (parent) code:

```
val strategy = OneForOneStrategy() {
  case _: Exception  => Escalate
  case _             => Escalate
}

val router: ActorRef =
  context.actorOf(Props[Worker].withRouter(FromConfig().withSupervisorStrategy(strategy)), name = "router")

def receive = {
  case ex: Exception =>
    log.info(ex.toString)
}
```

However, whenever I send a message to worker, it restarts instead of escalating to parent. Seems like overriding is not working.

Any idea please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escalating a failure does not mean that the exception is sent as a message to the parent actor but that the the parent actors supervision strategy is used to determine what to do.

Your controller/parent actor does not override `supervisionStrategy` and it therefore has the default strategy which is to restart on exception.